# How many purchases can he make if he purchases at least one item?

Tags: combinatorics

Rob is shopping for household necessities.  He sometimes buys items in bulk if there is a sale and sometimes does not buy any items at a particular store if those items are too expensive.  He has a budget that allows him to buy up to $2$ packs of diapers, $3$ cans of formula, $15$ containers of baby food and $4$ jugs of juice.  If he must buy at least one of these items, how many different purchases can be make?

The budget does not matter, only the last question. The final answer given to me was $959$ but I have no idea how to get it. I was trying the formula $2^n - 1$ but I don't know how to start it.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that Rob has three choices for how many packs of diapers he purchases, $0$, $1$, or $2$.  By similar reasoning, he has $3 + 1 = 4$ choices for how many cans of formula he purchases, $15 + 1 = 16$ choices for how many containers of baby food he purchases, and $4 + 1 = 5$ choices for how many jugs of juice he purchases.  Hence, by the Multiplication Principle, he can make $3 \cdot 4 \cdot 16 \cdot 5 = 960$ different purchases, but one of these options is purchasing none of the items.  Since he must purchase at least one item, the number of purchases he can make is $3 \cdot 4 \cdot 16 \cdot 5 - 1 = 959$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what techniques you have learnt.

One way is to use a generating function, add up all the coefficients of $x$ in the expansion of
$(1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^{14}+x^{15})(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^2)$

This yields a total of $960$, and after excluding $1$ (for no item chosen), yields the answer of $959$